# Magento 2.3 not sending order confirmation Email

Tags: magento, cron, smtp

i've recently moved my Magento 2.3.5 website to a new provider and since then i have some issues.
The most annoying one is that order confirmation Emails are not sent out.

SMTP configuration is ok, test email works fine.
Mageplaza SMTP is installed and shows many entries (contact form, shipment confirmation) but no order confirmation emails.

I think it's a cron issue but don't know where to look sincerely..

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the log exception files

Comment: Check your Magento root, there is a folder with name var and follow these flow-var → log and there will be a file with name exception.log. Open this file and check the errors

Comment: So what i've found is this:
[2021-03-20 13:58:12] main.CRITICAL: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag date invalid in Entity, line: 1 {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 2): DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag date invalid in Entity, line: 1 at /home/u314884553/domains/golfballs24.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Escaper.php:94)"} []
but not at the order time so i think has nothing to do with it..or?

Comment: Could someone help?